# Azure change destination IP NAT to local VM

Tags: firewall, azure, netflow

We have an Azure Windows VM created with Inbound security rules allowing UDP/9999 for Netflow traffic.  From the Windows VM we can capture traffic destined for the server.  The packets are showing the translation

> Source: Customer Public IP to Dest: Azure VM Public IP

Our App needs to have the following translation:

> Source: Customer Public IP to Dest: Azure VM Private IP

Is there anyway to change this translation on the Azure VM network Resource Group?

Answer (score 0):

An internet facing load balancer with a NAT rule should do it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal